# Iterate over an Active Record Relation in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following code:

```
@items = QuestionGroup.search(params[:search]).limit(50)
```

This returns an ActiveRecord relation. In the view I want to iterate through it so I use:

```
<% if @items.present? %>
    <%= @items.each do |r| %>
        <%= div_for r do %>
            <div><%= r.subject %></div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This does print r.subject to the view but it then follows it with the entire relation. e.g.

```
the pipe
[#<QuestionGroup id: **, subject: "the pipe", created_at: "*******", updated_at: "******"]
```

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: `<%= @items.each do |r| %>` to `<% @items.each do |r| %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
<%= @items.each do |r| %>
```

This line of code iterates over each of the relations and due to the '=' you output its content. Change it to:

```
<% @items.each do |r| %>
```

and you are good to go!

Comment: Thanks Phil. I will learn to be careful with erb one of these days :).

Comment: You are welcome :) I encountered this error myself in the beginning, this is how you learn ;)